# Why are sliders an active link in open space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created 3 sliders. When I hover over the icon it slides out to 300px, starting at 38px. Each slider has it's wrapper and then an image set to the right/absolute (more content will be added eventually). The images have a class of social_media_slide_icon. Each of these slides is then wrapped as a link.

The third one works perfect. It only shows 'clickable' when hovering over the 38px by 38px image (aka the wrapper). As it expands, the space it fells then becomes a link as well.

However, for the first two. It works the exact same but when hovering the mouse to the right of the starting slider, it shows as clickable. It seems as if it expands across the div that wraps all of this up, which is social_media. THIS DOES NOT HAPPEN FOR THE THIRD ONE.

There must be some reasonable explanation, however I have compared character by character and kind find a difference.

```js
 $("#social_media_piece_1_wrapper").mouseenter(function(){
  $("#social_media_piece_1_wrapper").animate({
   'width' : "300px"
  }); 
 }); 
 
 $("#social_media_piece_1_wrapper").mouseleave(function(){
  $("#social_media_piece_1_wrapper").animate({
   'width' : "38px"
  }); 
 }); 
 
 
 
 $("#social_media_piece_2_wrapper").mouseenter(function(){
  $("#social_media_piece_2_wrapper").animate({
   'width' : "300px"
  }); 
 }); 
 
 $("#social_media_piece_2_wrapper").mouseleave(function(){
  $("#social_media_piece_2_wrapper").animate({
   'width' : "38px"
  }); 
 }); 
 
 
 
 $("#social_media_piece_3_wrapper").mouseenter(function(){
  $("#social_media_piece_3_wrapper").animate({
   'width' : "300px"
  }); 
 });
 
 $("#social_media_piece_3_wrapper").mouseleave(function(){
  $("#social_media_piece_3_wrapper").animate({
   'width' : "38px"
  }); 
 });
```

```css
#social_media_piece_1_wrapper{
 position:relative;
 width:38px;
 height:38px;
 background-color:#232323; 
 border-top:1px solid #111111;
 border-bottom:1px solid #111111;
 border-top-right-radius:10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
 box-shadow: 3px 7px 3px black;
}


#social_media_piece_2_wrapper{
 position:relative;
 top:19px;
 width:38px;
 height:38px;
 background-color:#232323;
 border-top:1px solid #111111;
 border-bottom:1px solid #111111;
 border-top-right-radius:10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
 box-shadow: 3px 7px 3px black;
}


#social_media_piece_3_wrapper{
 position:relative;
 width:38px;
 height:38px;
 background-color:#232323;
 top:38px;
 border-top:1px solid #111111;
 border-bottom:1px solid #111111;
 border-top-right-radius:10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
 box-shadow: 3px 7px 3px black;
}

.social_media_slide_icon{
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 height:38px;
 width:38px;
 border-left:5px solid <?=$theme_color_2?>;
 border-top-right-radius:10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}

#social_media{
 width:300px;
 height:156px;
 position:relative;
 top:60px;
 border-left:5px solid #232323;
 left:-5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='social_media'>
   <a href=''><div id='social_media_piece_1_wrapper'>
    <img src='images/facebook_icon.png' class='social_media_slide_icon'>
   </div></a>
   <a href=''><div id='social_media_piece_2_wrapper'>
    <img src='images/twitter_icon.png' class='social_media_slide_icon'>
   </div></a>
   <a href=''><div id='social_media_piece_3_wrapper'>
    <img src='images/google_plus_icon.png' class='social_media_slide_icon'>
   </div></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Give `#social_media` a width of 38px ?

Comment: That fixed it. I had other plans for inside that div but I will figure out a work around. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your `#social_media` `width: 38px;` it works as expected for me. Not sure what was causing the third one to work as expected with your original code but I just checked it out on jsfiddle and that did the trick.